# use regex for detect multi string in nginx location and rewrite

Tags: regex, nginx, nginx-config, nginx-location

I want when a request is sent to the server and there is one of the string values of (movie|series|video|...) at the beginning, that string is removed and directed to the path where the data is stored.

this my nginx location config

```
 location ~ ^/(movie|series|video|...)/.*\.ts {
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
        add_header X-App-Id media-service-nginx;
        rewrite ^/(movie|series|video|...)/(.*)$ /$1 break;
        root /storage/media;
    }
```

And requests like these are sent to the server

```
http://api.media.loc/movie/2023/02/21/video-1080-chunk_intro_300.ts
http://api.media.loc/series/2023/02/21/video-1080-chunk_intro_200.ts
http://api.media.loc/video/2023/02/21/video-1080-chunk_intro_100.ts
```

Finally, the request should be redirected to the path, for example `/storage/media/2023/02/21/video-1080-chunk_intro_300.ts`

this config gives a 404 error for the multi string

But if a string is written in the config, it works correctly, `~ ^/movie/.*\.ts`

I want it to support multi rules `~ ^/(movie|series|video|...)/.*\.ts` and rewrite `^/(movie|series|video|...)/(.*)$ /$1` , this is not work , please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see a minor mistake in your regex which you used in your rewrite rule. You need to use `$2`. The variable `$1` represents the first capture group, which is the movie, series, or video part, while `$2` represents the second capture group, which is the rest of the path. You can read this post for getting insights around **[capturing groups.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-in-regular-expressions)**

Here's how it'll look like:

```bash
location ~ ^/(movie|series|video)/.*\.ts {
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
    add_header X-App-Id media-service-nginx;
    rewrite ^/(movie|series|video)/(.*)$ /$2 break;
    root /storage/media;
}
```